# Find all files in a folder

Tags: c#, file, directory

I am looking to create a program that finds all files of a certain type on my desktop and places them into specific folders, for example, I would have all files with .txt into the Text folder.

Any ideas what the best way would be to accomplish this? Thanks.

I have tried this:

```
string startPath = @"%userprofile%/Desktop";
string[] oDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(startPath, "");
Console.WriteLine(oDirectories.Length.ToString());

foreach (string oCurrent in oDirectories)
    Console.WriteLine(oCurrent);

Console.ReadLine();
```

It was not successful in finding all of the files.

Comment: What have you tried? I suggest you to start from [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo) and [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo)  classes.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

A lot of these answers won't actually work, having tried them myself. Give this a go:

```
string filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);

foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.txt"))
{
      Directory.Move(file.FullName, filepath + "\\TextFiles\\" + file.Name);
}
```

It will move all .txt files on the desktop to the folder `TextFiles`.

Answer (score 13):

First off; best practice would be to get the users Desktop folder with

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

Then you can find all the files with something like

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Note that with the above line you will find all files with a .txt extension in the Desktop folder of the logged in user AND all subfolders.

Then you could copy or move the files by enumerating the above collection like

```
// For copying...
foreach (string s in files)
{
   File.Copy(s, "C:\newFolder\newFilename.txt");
}

// ... Or for moving
foreach (string s in files)
{
   File.Move(s, "C:\newFolder\newFilename.txt");
}
```

Please note that you will have to include the filename in your `Copy()` (or `Move()`) operation. So you would have to find a way to determine the filename of at least the extension you are dealing with and not name all the files the same like what would happen in the above example.

With that in mind you could also check out the `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` classes.
These work in similair ways, but you can get information about your path-/filenames, extensions, etc. more easily

Check out these for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx

Comment: Doesn't `File.Copy` copy one file into another? Do you mean `File.Move`?

Comment: I figured he would get the idea ;) But for the sake of completeness I've added both options.

Comment: No problem ;) This will still fail in the foreach loop though, you're giving each file the same filename `newFilename.txt`

Answer (score 8):

You can try with Directory.GetFiles and fix your pattern

```
 string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*.txt");

 foreach (string file in files)
 {
    File.Copy(file, "....");
 }

 Or Move

 foreach (string file in files)
 {
    File.Move(file, "....");
 }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f