# counting the number of files inside a folder in a particular directory in c#

Tags: c#

I am writing  a program in c#. Suppose I have some folders in **Environment.CurrentDirectory**. The folders are named after different numbers (say: 1,2,3 etc). Inside each folder there are some files. I want to count the total number of files inside a particular folder (say folder '1'), how will I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861151/find-all-files-in-a-folder

Comment: i want to provide the folder name only and search in the current directory @Grant Winney
I will not provide the full folder path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. "path" contains the exact path to the wanted folder.

```
int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(path).Count();
```

This is how you combine paths:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "1");
```

Comment: But i want to provide the folder name only and search in the current directory @Maor Veitsman

Comment: I hope I'm understanding you correctly. You can use Path.Combine to create a proper full path. I edited my answer with a sample line of code.

Comment: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)---getting this error @Maor Veitsman

Comment: Add "using System.Linq;" in the beginning of your file.